# What is the difference between uwsgi protocol and wsgi protocol?

Tags: wsgi, uwsgi

I know uwsgi is the protocol implemented in uWSGI server. But what changes does it have as compared to wsgi?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The uwsgi protocol is a wire protocol used over the socket between processes with uWSGI. It cannot be compared to WSGI, which is a programmatic API for Python. The uwsgi protocol is more akin to FASTCGI, or SCGI. It is language agnostic. From memory there is very little difference between it and SCGI.

In short, that uwsgi has the name 'wsgi' in it was a bad idea as it is actually unrelated to WSGI. You still need an adapter to get from uwsgi to Python WSGI. In the case of uWSGI that is written as C code and embedded in uWSGI. One could write an adapter between uwsgi and other language APIs for web applications as well and uWSGI internal also has such things.

Comment: I understand the difference better now, though not completely. I guess I will need to get a little deeper into WSGI.

Comment: Where can I find the definition/spec for the wsgi wire protocol?  All searches are yielding results for the very different WSGI API.

Comment: There is no "WSGI wire protocol". As noted above, it is an API only.